# Can we have the self-rank on top in the Network-wide leaderboard too?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

In the [Leaderboard](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/meta.stackoverflow.com) page of individual sites, we can see our ranking for that particular site mentioned at the top of the actual list, which I feel is really nice as we need not actually search through the whole list to find our rank.

*Sample snap:*

[image: I'm on the top of MSO ;)]

So, can we have the same feature on the [Network-wide leaderboard](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) page too? I'd really like to know where I stand network wide as well, and not really search pages and pages to find my ranking.

[image: I'm missing in the network wide page :(]

Comment: ♪ [I love myself, I want you to love me, when I wear hats, I want to admire me, I search myself, and then I can find me, I forget myself, I want you to remind me... I don't want, anybody else, when I think about hats I rank myself...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Touch_Myself) ♪

Comment: @jmac - You're a genius :D You solved the mystery by combining both my posts here on MSO. *I love the hats and I love myself and I love seeing myself with the hats* ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely. I had postponed this because it required some bigger changes, but it's done now.